# Formattazione numeri in Python

Tags: python, formatting

I wanted to ask if anyone can help me format some numbers.

I'll give you some examples: first example {{'{: .2f}'. Format (number)}} is equivalent to: 1000000,00

second example: {{'{: n}'. format (number)}} equals 1.000.000,000000

I would like to get this formatting if possible 1.000.000,00

Thanks.

Comment: This is English only site. Please, translate your question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is not in English.

Comment: Hi, I wanted to ask if anyone can help me format some numbers.

I'll give you some examples: first example {{'{: .2f}'. Format (number)}} is equivalent to: 1000000,00.

second example: {{'{: n}'. format (number)}} equals 1,000,000.0000000.

I would like to get this formatting if possible 1,000,000.00

Thanks.

Comment: @RayFodarella you will get the help faster if you edit your question instead of posting question in english in the comments :)

Comment: yes, Done!.....

Answer (score 0):

you are really close to the solution.

```
num = 165461.3165465
num = f'{num:,.2f}'
```

This code gives you `165,461.32`

Comment: i want to 165.461,32

Comment: So you are probably looking for the Italian formatting right? (I'm Italian as well). You may want to use a library like "locale" or "babel". I've found it easier with babel with something like this: `from babel.numbers import format_decimal
num = 165461.3165465
num = f"{format_decimal(num, locale='it_IT')}"`

Comment: You can use f-strings for better code, instead of `str.format()`

Comment: Yes, it makes way more sense thanks! Just updated the answer with `num = f'{num:,.2f}'` for future reference ;)

Comment: Yes correct. First I have to install the right library with the pip command? Thanks

Comment: Yeah, as easy as `pip install babel`

Comment: I'll try thanks a lot

Comment: this is my code   <td style="font-size:small">{{'{:n}'.format(dati[i].budget)}}</td>  if  i'll try     f"{format_decimal(dati[i].budget, locale='it_IT')}" they give me an error

Comment: What's the error? Seems like you are using flask or similar to render an html page.. Try to do the formatting on the backend and just send the string as a variable to put inside the jinja code (the error you got is probably cause the `format_decimal()` function is not imported)

Comment: Yes, right .
I am using flask.
The error was expected token 'end of print statement', got 'string'